# How to filter documents by multiple conditions on Array of Objects in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Suppose, I have a collection in which each document looks like following:

[image: document schema]

Is it possible to find all documents of this collection based on following multiple conditions on Objects in modules array.

```
{_id: OID123, status: available} and {_id: OID456, status: complete}
```

So that, it should return document similar to following:

```
{modules: [{_id: OID123, status: available}, {_id: OID456, status: complete}, {_id: OID789, ...}] }
```

[Schema/Configuration on Mongo playground for this problem](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XfkKsizZrg-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone!

I managed to solve this problem by following query using $all operator:

```
db.collection.find({
  "modules": {
    $all: [
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          "_id": "OID1",
          "status": "available"
        }
      },
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          "_id": "OID2",
          "status": "complete"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

You can find more details on the mentioned playground link:

[Mongo playground link with Query and example schema for this problem](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_J7I1Z-DvzY)